# SharePoint 2013 - View Threshold alert when filtering columns

Tags: 2013, threshold

I'm using SharePoint 2013. I have 5000+ items in one of my libraries. I already created a custom View that shows fewer items based on creation date. It shows fewer items now but when trying to select a value in Created By field, the following alert message shows. But when selecting two or more, the filter works well and vice versa. Is there a workaround for this? Or prevents this alert from appearing?

[image: view threshold alert message]

The fields in these libraries were already indexed and if I'm not mistaken, Created By field is indexed by default? And I have no idea why some HTML tags are included in the alert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (5000 items) enforced by the administrator](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43183/this-view-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-exceeds-the-list-view-threshold-5000-i)

Comment: Thanks for the reference Graham but it's not possible for me to increase the threshold limit and is not a recommended solution

Comment: There's additional comments in that thread by diptarag that go towards creating indexes on the columns, such as the date, to limit the view.

Comment: Updated my question. Already indexed the columns